# PHP syntax error, unexpected 'elseif'

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax, syntax-error

I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'elseif' (T_ELSEIF) in C:\...\functions.php on line 6
```

This is the whole content of functions.php:

```
<?php
// prints the suitable string based on the chosen language
function lecho ($cs,$sk,$en) {
    global $lang;
    if ($lang=="cs") echo $cs;​
    elseif ($lang=="​sk") echo $​sk;​
    elseif ($lang=="​en") echo $​en;​​ // line 7
}
?>
```

What's wrong? This seams like such a basic thing!

Comment: You have some weird hidden characters in your code. You might just want to rewrite it.

Comment: The answers are useless, your code is perfectly fine. The only problem are *non-printable characters* after some closing brackets, dollar signs and semicolons.

Comment: No there are some hidden characters, re-write the code. agreed with @Rizier123.

Comment: This solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

You're just missing a space:  it's `else if`, not `elseif`.

Comment: Yeah this is not the correct answer.

Comment: True enough!  Didn't know that version.  Turns out it was just hidden junk in the code.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use `{'code here'}` after an if/elseif/else statement. The correct way to go about this would be:

```
<?php
// prints the suitable string based on the chosen language
function lecho ($cs,$sk,$en) {
    global $lang;
    if ($lang=="cs") {
        echo $cs;​
    } elseif ($lang=="​sk") {
        echo $​sk;​
    } elseif ($lang=="​en") {
        echo $​en;​​
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

And it is simple. You just need to correct syntax for if/elseif

```
<?php
// prints the suitable string based on the chosen language
function lecho ($cs,$sk,$en) {
    global $lang;
    if ($lang=="cs") 
    {
        echo $cs;​
    }
    elseif ($lang=="​sk")
    { 
        echo $​sk;​
    }
    elseif ($lang=="​en")
    { 
        echo $​en;​​ // line 7
    }
}
?>
```